# socket programming getting input

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to establish a connection between client and server and when once it's successful,
a menu screen will be shown prompting the user whether he wants to 
1)input a message 
2)exit the program.

the problem I face was when I key in one, It will return me the output shown below

Client
output(It will just keep returning "I got your msg whenever I enter '1' without having the user to input the message first until I press ctrl+c")

```
Main Menu
        ----------------------
 1. option 1
 2. option 2
 Enter your choice1
 Please enter the message: I got your msg
 Main Menu
        ----------------------
 1. option 1
 2. option 2
 Enter your choice1
 Please enter the message: I got your msg
 Main Menu
        ----------------------
  1. option 1
  2. option 2
  Enter your choice1
  Please enter the message: I got your msg
```

Server

```
  Here is the msg:

  Here is the msg:

  Here is the msg:
```

What I have currently.

server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void doPrcoessing(int sock) {
int n;
char buffer[256];
bzero(buffer,256);
n =read(sock,buffer,255);

if(n < 0) {
    perror("Error from reading socket");
    exit(1);
}

    printf("Here is the msg: %s\n",buffer);
    n=write(sock,"I got your msg",18);

if(n<0) {
    perror("Error writing to socket");
    exit(1);
}
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int sockfd,pid,newsockfd,portno,clientn;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
    char buffer[256];
    bool connected;
    int n;

    /*call socket() function*/
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
    perror("Error opening socket");
    exit(1);
    }
   // printf("socket retrieve success\n");

   /*Initialize socket structure*/

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    /*bind the host address using bind() call*/
    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("Error on binding!");
        exit(1);
    }
    int yes =1;
    if(setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
    }
    /*start listening for clients, will go into sleep mode and wait for incoming     connection*/
    listen(sockfd,5);
clientn = sizeof(cli_addr);    
 while(connected == false) {
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,&clientn);

    if(newsockfd < 0) {
        perror("Error on accept!");
        exit(1);
        }

    /*Create chlid process*/
    pid =fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Error on fork!");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        /*Client process*/
        close(sockfd);
        doPrcoessing(newsockfd);
        return 0;   
    }
    else
    {
        close(newsockfd);
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void print(void);

int sockfd, portno, n; 
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;
bool loop = false; 
char options[100];
char buffer[256];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
while(loop==false) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
 /* Create a socket point */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)  {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
  }
 server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
 if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
 }

 bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

 /* connect to the server */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error connecting");
        exit(1);
 }

int choice;  
//print();
    if(choice !=2) {
        printf("Main Menu");
        printf("\n\t----------------------");
        printf("\n 1. option 1");
        printf("\n 2. option 2");
        printf("\n Enter your choice");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice) {
        case 1: print();
            break;
        case 2: exit(0);
            break;
        default: printf("Invalid choice!\n");
            break;

        }   
    }
}
close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}

void print(void)    {
 /*ask for a message from the user, this message will be read by server */
printf("Please enter the message: ");
        bzero(buffer,256);
            fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
        /* Send message to the server */
            n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0)  {
                perror("ERROR writing to socket");
                exit(1);
            }

        /* read server response */
            bzero(buffer,256);
            n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
            if (n < 0)  {
                perror("ERROR reading from socket");
                exit(1);
            }

        printf("%s\n",buffer);  
}
```

Comment: Closely read the man-pages for `read`/`write` and learn that at least for sockets those two functions do not necessarily read/write as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Comment: OT: Also `read`/`write` return `ssize_t` not `int`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` before `fgets(..., stdin)` will solve your problem.

Comment: Consider changing whatever book our tutorial you use to learn to something that is IP version agnostic. For instance `sockaddr_in` is strictly `IPv4` whereas it's just as easy (and much more IPv6 friendly)  to use `sockaddr_storage`, which can contain `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6`.

Comment: Please leave the question as it was, don't remove the code. That's not how SO works. I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

The reason WHY `fgets()` fails to read buffer from input is that your `scanf` left a new line character in input buffer.

So your `fgets` will return soon after calling it.

codes in client.c should be modified as below:

```
<code...>
printf("Please enter the message: \n");  
fflush(stdout);  
bzero(buffer,256);  
read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, sizeof(buffer));  
/* Send message to the server */  
n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));  
</code...>
```

also, codes in server.c should be modified as below:

```
<code...>
scanf("%d ", &choice);
</code...>
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` does not consume the newline that the user hits after making a selection.  But the `fgets` immediately does, and nothing else.  The correct solution is to stop using `scanf` (that's the correct solution for any program that uses `scanf`, IMO).  But it's probably simpler to add a space to the format string:

```
scanf( "%d " ... )
```